# What does 'typeof $(document)['on']' do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $inputPswd1 = $('#checkInput01'),
    $inputPswd2 = $('#checkInput02'),
    $inputPswds =  $inputPswd1.add($inputPswd2); 

var bindOn = function () {
    return typeof $(document)['on'] ? 'on' : 'bind';
}();

$inputPswds[bindOn]('keyup._passchk', function(e){
});
```

This code snippet is written as part of input validation.Can anyone tell what these lines do:

```
typeof $(document)['on']
```

and

```
$inputPswds[bindOn]('keyup._passchk', function(e) {});
```

`checkInput01` and `checkInput02` are id's of two inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof $(document)['on']
```

This is used to check if the `on` method is available on the DOM object. Before jQuery version 1.7 it will not be available.

```
$inputPswds[bindOn]('keyup._passchk', function(e) {});
```

This calls either the `on` or `bind` method, depending on the result of the statement above, and assigns a `keyup` event handler to the elements in the `$inputPswds` jQuery object.

Note that if you're using any version of jQuery since 1.7, then the check is pretty much redundant and can be removed to just simply call `on()`

Comment: Wouldn't `$.fn.on ? 'on' : 'bind'` be faster?

Comment: Most likely, however the whole point of the code is largely useless.

Comment: Thank you McCrossan.I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of jQuery do not have `on` method. The code snippet uses `typeof` for checking existence of the `on` method. If the jQuery object does not have `.on` method it uses the `.bind` method for attaching event handlers.

Also note that the code has a bug! `typeof` returns a string and non-empty strings are truthy values in JavaScript. The function always returns`.on`.  The function body should be:

```
return typeof $(document)['on'] !== 'undefined' ? 'on' : 'bind';
```

Another option is:

```
return jQuery.fn.on ? 'on' : 'bind';
```